# Do I need to buy twillio phone number on monthly basis?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have bought a twilio phone number after 1 month. I'm getting unknown from number error from sdk. Do I need to update the from number for everymonth?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You do not need to update the from number every month, but numbers do incur a monthly charge. I would make sure you Twilio account balance is in credit.

If that's not the problem, can you update your question with the code you are using?